# Video Padding issue

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I am currently having an issue here.

I have this page here: http://goo.gl/V0352s

[image]

Now my youtube video was cut off (its not even acting responsive) and I am trying to figure it out what might be the issue and how to solve it using CSS. i have the ff: HTML:

```
    <div style="width: 46%; float:left;height: 299px;">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/h8NChiwfkFs?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>

<div style="float: right; width: 46%">
<h5>Description:</h5>
<p>Promotional Video for iLiveAccountable. A local life coaching and training company. Owned by Tony Beatty and Michael Gardner.</p>
<h5>Company</h5>
<p>iLiveAccountable</p>
<h5>Project Link</h5>
<p><a href="https://goo.gl/JZ0Hfw" target="_blank">https://goo.gl/JZ0Hfw</a>
</p></div>
```

You can try to right click inspect element on Chrome to check on this real time.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Add this CSS:</strike>

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .postid-146 iframe {
        height: 31.5vw;
        max-height: 315px;
    }
}
```

After several failed attempts to make this work responsively, I made a script that resizes the iframe based on its set `width` and `height` attributes, and the actual `width`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    $('iframe').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        'height': ($(this).attr('height') * $(this).width() / $(this).attr('width')) + 'px'
      });
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: the video was cut off

Comment: Still the same. It won't make it responsive on mobile devices starting at 768px.

Comment: iframe {
    height: auto;
}

.postid-146 iframe {
    height: 315px;
}

.fleft{
width: 46%; 
float:left;
}

.fright{
float: right; 
width: 46%
}

media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.fleft{
float:none;
}

.fright{
float:none;
}


}

media (min-width: 768px) {
    .postid-146 iframe {
        height: 31.5vw;
        max-height: 315px;
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100335/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-rodel-garcia).